# How to use "$match" and "$or" in mongo aggregation in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to load the matched documents into a temporary collection using aggregation query. Actually, I'm able to load all the matched documents into the temporary collection of MongoDB but my java program is throwing Null pointer exception at the for loop.

I'm totally stuck over here. May I know the reason for Null Pointer exception in this scenario . And can anyone please suggest me regarding the same ...

```
 Document query = {"$or":[{"roll":1,"joiningDate":{"$gte":ISODate("2017-04-11T00:00:00Z")}},{"roll":2,"joiningDate":{"$gte": ISODate("2017-03-17T00:00:00Z")}}]};

            Document match = new Document("$match",new Document("$or",query));

            Document out =new Document("$out","TempCol");

            System.out.println("Before Aggregation");

            AggregateIterable<Document> resultAgg = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match,out));

            System.out.println("After aggregation");

            for (Document doc : resultAgg){


                    System.out.println("The result of aggregation match:-");

            }

            System.out.println("Completed");
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to keep the pipeline structured in one variable.

But the general idea here is use `Document` where you see `{}` and `Arrays.asList` where you see `[]`:

```
List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.<Document>asList(
  new Document("$match",
    new Document("$or", Arrays.<Document>asList(
      new Document("roll", 1)
        .append("joiningDate", new Document(
          "$gte", new DateTime(2017,04,11,0,0,0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()
        )),
      new Document("controlId", 2)
        .append("joiningDate", new Document(
          "$gte", new DateTime(2017,03,17,0,0,0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()
        ))
    ))
  ),
  new Document("$out","TempCol")
);

AggregateIterable<Document> resultAgg = controlIssueCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Also make sure when constructing a `Date` object with whatever your favorite construction method here is ( for me `org.joda.time.DateTime` ) that you are working with time in UTC, unless you really mean otherwise. And if you are comparing with values stored in MongoDB as shown in the shell, then you mean UTC.